# Meaning of "put (one's) finger on something"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "put (one's) finger on something" in this sentence? What's the best summary of this text? What do you say if you want to sum it up in one or two sentences?

> A lot of readers, wanting to put their finger on why the affluent world they live in makes them so uneasy, will want to cheer.

Source: The sentence comes from the opening paragraph of a book review in *[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2007/jan/27/booksonhealth.society)*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I feel the other answers have missed a lot of the subtlety of the phrase.

It's not merely to point something out.
It's a recognition or demonstration of **Insightfulness** depending on the usage.

To put your finger on something is to reach the most vital point of the argument and do it with precision, typically pushing past any complexity to reach the crux of the problem.

In the context of being "unable to put my finger on it", it's a comment that insight into the problem isn't being forthcoming.

It stems from a family of metaphors around the idea of pinning or nailing things in place so that they are easier to work with.

Comment: I think this makes a key point. This is why, perhaps more often than not, we see this phrase is used in the negative: _There's something strange about this town, but I can't quite put my finger on it_.

Comment: One could say I've "put my finger" on the answer to the actual question :P

Comment: It means "understand"

Answer (score 17):

The answer by Tᴚoɯɐuo explains the concept pretty well, but here's a supporting reference:

***[put your finger on sth:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/put-your-finger-on-sth)***
​

> to discover the exact reason why a situation is the way it is, especially when something is wrong:
>
> - There's something odd about him, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I don't think it always involves "discovery". It is post-discover.

Comment: I wonder if this expression is the same as or similar to  [keeping your finger on **the pulse**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/have-keep-your-finger-on-the-pulse)

Comment: For what it is worth I've only heard this phrase used when it is prefixed with "can't" e.g. "I can't quite put my finger on it." I've never heard it used in the way the OP describes it.

Comment: So we did NOT get a compelling result guys!

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: "Put" is both present and paste tense of "to put". Pre-discovery or post-discovery is a matter of tense. The meaning of "put your finger on" does not change.

Comment: @BruceWayne: `It's always used when something is not clear. The example in this answer is confusing` How is the example in this answer not "not clear"? It specifically stresses not knowing the thing that is odd about [him].

Comment: @Levi Morrison: This has nothing to do with **keeping your finger on the pulse**. That means to monitor a situation, not to explain it.

Comment: @Flater sorry, I had to reread it a few times. It makes sense, for some reason I wasn't reading it correctly at first.

Answer (score 5):

It means "to point out something", especially as the explanation for something else.

> I think the car needs new spark plugs.
>   --You've put your finger on it. It isn't the distributor at all.

Or

> The reason so many blue collar voters voted for a president whose aim was to destroy labor unions is that he could seem anti-elitist.
>   -- I'm not so sure, but you may have put your finger on it.

So, your text can be paraphrased:

A lot of readers, who would like to know why the affluent world they live in makes them feel very uneasy, will want to shout their support (for the author).

Comment: I don't think I agree with "point out" at all. It more means "to precisely determine something".

Comment: @Muzer: What is so different about identifying the explanation for something and determining something?  They seem synonymous to me.

Comment: They are synonymous, but neither is synonymous with "to point out something". To point something is much more about something people already knew or could have seen themselves, but the act of pointing it out specifically draws attention to it. For instance, "I'd like to point out the fact that Charlie is new here, so perhaps we should explain what's going on". To put one's finger on something is much more about the act of figuring out an explanation, especially to a situation that everyone can see but the explanation behind it is not known.

Comment: To *put your finger on something* does not **always** mean to "determine" and that's why I said "to point something out, *especially* as the explanation for something".

Comment: When doesn't it mean "to determine"? I'm struggling to think of a use case where it would mean something different, but that might just be a mental block!

Comment: Perhaps a mental block, because you're thinking only of the figurative meaning of the expression. When it is used literally it has only the meaning to point something out:   "Class, here on the blackboard are four shapes, a circle, a rectangle, an octagon and a hexagon. Muzer, can you stop bothering Jenny and come up to the blackboard and put your finger on the hexagon?"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's true, but it's a totally different use of the phrase than what OP is talking about. We're not discussing the *literal* usage of "put your finger on something". This is about the *figurative* usage. And I'd argue no one would actually say "put your finger on the hexagon"; more common would be "point to the hexagon".

Comment: @ell: The figurative meaning is derived from the literal meaning. And that "point to" is more frequent doesn't mean much in this context. **put your finger on** is a fairly common phrase in elementary education. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put%20your%20finger%20on%20the%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 1):

To put your finger on something is to point it out in a way that educates the listener, to the point where the listener is surprised is not only surprised at the accuracy of the answer, but questions whether they would have understood it that well without your help.  It's used to define presumably accurate answers to questions others have found difficult to even define.  Think of the act of pointing out something on a map or other document...if you "put your finger on" the thing you're looking for, you've clearly identified it rather than just knowing the general area to look.